# Formatting a question consistently

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to format my assignment in a question and answer format.

```
\newcommand{\question}[2]{\textbf{Question #1}\\#2\\}
```

This command is fine for my intents and purposes. No indentation required. No funny business. I have subquestions however, which require indentations, and I'm not sure how to achieve it in latex. Currently, my subquestion new command is defined as

```
\newcommand{\pquestion}[2]{${}^{}\qquad$\textbf{#1) } #2\\}
```

This works fine when the subquestion is one line, but I want the next line to be aligned with the first line, when it does spill over to the next line.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: Don't use \\ for that purpose!

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, an enumerate might work. but my whole document will be in a big enumerate environment at that point, and I'm not 100% sure how I feel about that. Whatever works though, right?

Comment: @Michael It will definitely work with a long document.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about big enumerate environments. You can customise things with `enumitem` and it will work fine.

Comment: @Michael You can do the formatting by measuring the natural width of `c)` followed by a space using `\settowidth`, then put a minipage of \linewidth-measured_width. But minipages don't break accross pages. You can use LaTeX's `\@hangfrom`, but the effect will only last one paragraph (I assume it's the same with the `hanging` package). All in all, using a real enumeration environment (as provided by `enumitem`) is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Purton's comment solves the problem. Here I only make some developments: using counters to reduce the number of arguments to the `\question` command and use `\setlist` for global settings of subquestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcounter{question}
\newcommand\question[1]{%
    \stepcounter{question}
    \textbf{\large Question \arabic{question}}\par#1\par}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{{\bfseries a)}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\question{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibu-lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metusrhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eutellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
\item Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretiumquis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aeneanfaucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla
\end{enumerate}

\question{Calculate the value of $1+1$?}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hence, calculate the value of $1+2$.
\item Is $2$ the only sum of $1$ and $1$? Give an explanation.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nevertheless, please check out some available classes and packages for exam papers (I don't use them often though, so I can't provide anything here). They are much more customizable.